# How to call a method after creating the instance in Ninject?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, ioc-container

I wanna do an initializing just after the instance created with Ninject.
I written the following code:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<IHardwareService>().To<HardwareServiceClient>().InRequestScope().OnActivation(client =>
    {
        InitializeServiceHeader(); // never execute
        client.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new IncludeClientData());
    });
}
```

I expected to `InitializeServiceHeader();` calls after the following code:

```
var instance = new StandardKernel().Get<HardwareServiceClient>();
```

But never `InitializeServiceHeader();` call.
How should do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the `InitializeServiceHeader()` won't be called as the type binding is for `IHardwareService`.

If you have a class called `HardwareServiceTest` and if it's constructor has a parameter of type IHardwareService

```
public Class HardwareServiceTest
{
    public HardwareServiceTest(IHardwareService serv)
    {
       //do something with serv;
    }
}
```

In this case, calling,

`new StandardKernel().Get<HardwareServiceTest>()`

will trigger a call to InitializeServiceHeader().

Comment: So, How should I define binding to call `InitializeServiceHeader`

Comment: My answer formatting was not correct earlier as i typed it in my phone. I have updated it. Please see if it makes more sense now. :)

Comment: Your type binding logic will be triggered only if Ninject needs to resolve IHardwareService